# How use parsing given data which i get from $.post success?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

***Good day.***

***Code:***

```
      $.post("./AutoCompliteFind/", {
        term:form_data
        },
        function(data){

        alert(data);

});
```

***success data return json code:***

```
[{"fullname":"\u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440 \u041b\u0430\u0432\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e","university_name":"\u0411\u0413\u0423 \u0438\u043c. \u041f\u0435\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0433\u043e\r\n","city":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430","image":"http:\/\/cs405620.vk.me\/u6299927\/e_f04977ac.jpg"}]
```

Tell me please how use parsing given data ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @nevermind i have json in array. if i use `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); alert(obj.fullname);` i get *undefened*. http://i.stack.imgur.com/TQVum.png

Comment: it's in an array, use: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); alert(obj[0].fullname);` (note the `[0]`). don't forget to decode utf8 ([tutorial](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.ca/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html))

Comment: You have a parsing problem server side. This usually happens with utf conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use eval

```
$.post("./AutoCompliteFind/", {
        term:form_data
        },
        function(data){

        var obj = eval(data);
        alert(obj[0].city);



});
```

Try this new version, I used and it worked